# Is gobuffalo able to generate my tables automatically?

Tags: database, go, buffalo

I have this structure:

```
type User struct {
    ID        int
    CreatedAt int
    UpdatedAt int

    DeviceUniqueIdentifier string

    Sessions []Session `has_many:"sessions"`
}
```

I have no idea how to export this in fizz, so I did so:

```
buffalo pop generate model User
```

To my surprise, it actually generated a User and put a table in the database, but neither the table nor the structure are as expected.

Here is the new User struct:

```
...
type User struct {
    ID        uuid.UUID `json:"id" db:"id"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `json:"created_at" db:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `json:"updated_at" db:"updated_at"`
}
...
```

Is there any way to generate passing some fields? Or is there a way to convert the structure to a table automatically?

Comment: It seems there is no way to do it with soda generators right now. You can generate user with `DeviceUniqueIdentifier` but have to add relationship by yourself editing both model and migration.

Answer (score 1):

There's a way to generate a model passing some fields:

```
buffalo pop generate model User id:int device_unique_identifier
```

You have to add your columns definition after the name of the model. The column syntax allows you to give the column type (by default it's considered as a string).

You'll have to add your **has_many** relation by hand though, relations are not yet supported by the generator.

Comment: I was looking for something like what GORM does in `db.AutoMigrate(&User{})`.